# Using pandas to read JSON file for Python analysis

Tags: python, json, pandas, analysis

I'm running into some issues, trying to load a JSON file in my Python editor so that I can run some analysis on the data within.

The JSON file is in the following folder: `'C:\Users\Admin\JSON files\file1.JSON'`

It contains the following tweet data (this is just one record, there are hundreds in there):

```
{
    "created": "Fri Mar 13 18:09:33 GMT 2014",
    "description": "Tweeting the latest Playstation news!",
    "favourites_count": 4514,
    "followers": 235,
    "following": 1345,
    "geo_lat": null,
    "geo_long": null,
    "hashtags": "",
    "id": 2144411414,
    "is_retweet": false,
    "is_truncated": false,
    "lang": "en",
    "location": "",
    "media_urls": "",
    "mentions": "",
    "name": "Playstation News",
    "original_text": null,
    "reply_status_id": 0,
    "reply_user_id": 0,
    "retweet_count": 4514,
    "retweet_id": 0,
    "score": 0.0,
    "screen_name": "SevenPS4",
    "source": "<a href=\"http://twitterfeed.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">twitterfeed</a>",
    "text": "tweetinfohere",
    "timezone": "Amsterdam",
    "url": null,
    "urls": "http://bit.ly/1lcbBW6",
    "user_created": "2013-05-19",
    "user_id": 13313,
    "utc_offset": 3600
}
```

I am using the following code to try and test this data:

```
import json
import pandas as pa
z = pa.read_json('C:\Users\Admin\JSON files\file1.JSON')
d = pa.DataFrame.from_dict([{k:v} for k,v in z.iteritems() if k in ["retweet_count", "user_id", "is_retweet"]])
print d.retweet_count.sum()
```

When I run this, it successfully reads the JSON file then prints out a list of the retweet_count's like this:

`0, 4514
1, 300
2, 450
3, 139` etc etc

My questions:
How do I actually sum up all of the retweet_count/user_id values rather than just listing them like shown above?

How do I then divide this sum by the number of entries to get an average?

How can I choose a sample size of the JSON data rather than use it all? (I thought it was d.iloc[:10] but that doesn't work)

With the 'is_retweet' field in the JSON file, is it possible to make a count for the amount of false/trues that are given? IE within the JSON file, I want the number of tweets that were retweeted and the number that weren't.

Thanks in advance, yeah I'm pretty new to this..

`z.info()` gives:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 506 entries, 0 to 505
Data columns (total 31 columns):
created             506 non-null object
description         506 non-null object
favourites_count    506 non-null int64
followers           506 non-null int64
following           506 non-null int64
geo_lat             10 non-null float64
geo_long            10 non-null float64
hashtags            506 non-null object
id                  506 non-null int64
is_retweet          506 non-null bool
is_truncated        506 non-null bool
lang                506 non-null object
location            506 non-null object
media_urls          506 non-null object
mentions            506 non-null object
name                506 non-null object
original_text       172 non-null object
reply_status_id     506 non-null int64
reply_user_id       506 non-null int64
retweet_id          506 non-null int64
retweet_count       506 non_null int64
score               506 non-null int64
screen_name         506 non-null object
source              506 non-null object
status_count        506 non-null int64
text                506 non-null object
timezone            415 non-null object
url                 273 non-null object
urls                506 non-null object
user_created        506 non-null object
user_id             506 non-null int64
utc_offset          506 non-null int64
dtypes: bool(2), float64(2), int64(11), object(16)`

How come it is showing retweet_count and user_id as objects when I run d.info()?

Comment: df.info() is showing the columns as non-null objects, when I assume they must be values, right? How can I change them to values, rather than objects?`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
retweet_count    1 non-null object
user_id    1 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)`

Comment: What is the datatype of `z`?

Comment: check my edit at the bottom @myacobucci

Comment: Not exactly sure, I've honestly never used pandas before, I just scanned through the documentation real quick for the methods and classes you were using to get an understanding of them. throwing an `int(retweet_count_value)` should change those into integers without problems.

Comment: sorry, but where does that line go?

Comment: Whenever you are handling the value of a `retweet_count` so in my example below, `sum+=int(d.retweet_count[items])`

Comment: @user1745447 please show z.head() rather than z.info(), possibly anonomize results.

Answer (score 0):

`d.retweet_count` is a list of dictionaries for your `retweet_counts` correct?

So to get the sum:

```
keys = d.retweet_count.keys()
sum = 0
for items in keys:
    sum+=d.retweet_count[items]
```

To get the average:

```
avg = sum/len(keys)
```

Now to get a sample size just divide up `keys`:

```
sample_keys = keys[0:10]
```

to get the mean

```
for items in sample_keys:
     sum+=d.retweet_count[items]
avg = sum/len(sample_keys)
```

Comment: I think when I used the following line `d = pa.DataFrame.from_dict([{k:v} for k,v in z.iteritems() if k in ["retweet_count", "user_id", "is_retweet"]])` it turned my value columns into objects so that I couldn't run sum/mean/etc on them. will try the sample size in a sec, thanks.

Comment: When you run `print d.retweet_count` what is the exact output?

Comment: I have fixed that problem now thanks, having a problem now with trying to use samples of the JSON data, rather than all of it. I have `z = pa.read_json('C:\Users\Admin\JSON files\file1.JSON')` as before, but I wish to use sample of 100/200 of the retweet_count so I can find mean/max/etc of diff size samples. I've tried `keys = z.retweet_count.keys()
sample_keys = keys[:200]`, then calling the mean with `sample_keys.mean`, but it's not working, any ideas @myacobucci thanks

Comment: At what point do you get an error? sample_keys are just the key values for your sample size. They are not the values... you have to make a list of your values.

Comment: There is no method called mean... You have to calculate it yourself as I did before to get the average... I've added another example that shows you how to use the sample_keys.. though this should have been obvious.

Comment: Mean is a method in pandas, I'm getting when trying to do the keys: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'long'`

Comment: This is why I asked for the output. Your trying to add a method to a number.